# What is "Rewards" in Ryanair dashboard?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, ryanair

I recently noticed that Ryanair has a "Rewards" section on their dashboard.

Clicking this options only tells me that I don't qualify yet to any offer:

[image]

I tried to find out a bit more on the FAQ, but nothing really substantial came up.

I googled and apparently there were some news, a couple of months ago, about Ryanair loyalty program being introduced. It said something about simplicity and being different from others, but again nothing really substantial.

Does anyone know anything about this and what kind of benefits the loyalty program / rewards gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching through [Ryanair's twitter account](https://twitter.com/ryanair) shows that they're constantly being asked this very question, but the only relevant information provided so far is [on this section of their website](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/myryanair-reward#0-0):

> €10 Travel credit reward for myRyanair sign-up
>
> Any NEW customer signing up to myRyanair and completing a full profile between Sept  7th – 9th inclusive will be entitled to a €10 travel credit off their next Ryanair flight departing Oct 1st – Dec 18th and Jan 10th – Jan 31st. Flight bookings must be made between Sept 7th – Sept 21st.

It's likely that other reward programs would show up soon, but this is currently the only one.